# DBI connect, failed: FATAL: sorry, too many clients already

Tags: database, perl, postgresql, cron

I am running a crontab as described below :

```
* 1 * * * /var/fdp/reportingscript/an_outgoing_tps_report.pl
* 1 * * * /var/fdp/reportingscript/an_processed_rule_report.pl
* 1 * * * /var/fdp/reportingscript/sdp_incoming_traffic_tps_report.pl
* 1 * * * /var/fdp/reportingscript/en_outgoing_tps_report.pl
* 1 * * * /var/fdp/reportingscript/en_processed_rule_report.pl
* 1 * * * /var/fdp/reportingscript/rs_incoming_traffic_report.pl
* 1 * * * /var/fdp/reportingscript/an_summary_report.pl
* 1 * * * /var/fdp/reportingscript/en_summary_report.pl
* 1 * * * /var/fdp/reportingscript/user_report.pl
```

and getting an error : ( for all scripts the error is same)

DBI connect('dbname=scs;host=192.168.18.23;port=5432','postgres',...) failed: FATAL:  sorry, too many clients already at /var/fdp/reportingscript/sdp_incoming_traffic_tps_report.pl line 38.

Moreover, if I am running the script manually one at a time, it doesn't show any error.

For your reference i am attaching the script also for which I have shown the above error:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use FindBin;
use lib $FindBin::Bin;
use Time::Local;
use warnings;
use DBI;
use File::Basename;
use CONFIG;
use Getopt::Long;
use Data::Dumper;

my $channel;
my $circle;
my $daysbefore;
my $dbh;
my $processed;
my $discarded;
my $db_name     = "scs";
my $db_vip      = "192.168.18.23";
my $db_port     = "5432";
my $db_user     = "postgres";
my $db_password = "postgres";
#### code to redirect all console output in log file
my ( $seco_, $minu_, $hrr_, $moday_, $mont_, $years_ ) = localtime(time);
$years_ += 1900;
$mont_  += 1;
my $timestamp = sprintf( "%d%02d%02d", $years_, $mont_, $moday_ );
$timestamp .= "_" . $hrr_ . "_" . $minu_ . "_" . $seco_;
print "timestamp is $timestamp \n";
my $logfile = "/var/fdp/log/reportlog/sdp_incoming_report_$timestamp";
print "\n output files is " . $logfile . "\n";
open( STDOUT, ">", $logfile ) or die("$0:dup:$!");
open STDERR, ">&STDOUT" or die "$0: dup: $!";

my ( $sec_, $min_, $hr_, $mday_, $mon_, $year_ ) = localtime(time);

$dbh = DBI->connect( "DBI:Pg:dbname=$db_name;host=$db_vip;port=$db_port",
    "$db_user", "$db_password", { 'RaiseError' => 1 } );
print "\n Dumper is " . $dbh . "\n";
my $sthcircle = $dbh->prepare("select id,name from circle");
$sthcircle->execute();

while ( my $refcircle = $sthcircle->fetchrow_hashref() ) {
    print "\n dumper for circle is " . Dumper($refcircle);
    my $namecircle = uc( $refcircle->{'name'} );
    my $idcircle   = $refcircle->{'id'};
    $circle->{$namecircle} = $idcircle;
    print "\n circle name : " . $namecircle . "id is " . $idcircle;
}

sub getDate {
    my $daysago = shift;
    $daysago = 0 unless ($daysago);
    my @months = qw(Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec);
    my ( $sec, $min, $hour, $mday, $mon, $year, $wday, $yday, $isdst ) = localtime( time - ( 86400 * $daysago ) );
    # YYYYMMDD, e.g. 20060126
    $year_ = $year + 1900;
    $mday_ = $mday;
    $mon_  = $mon + 1;
    return sprintf( "%d-%02d-%02d", $year + 1900, $mon + 1, $mday );
}

GetOptions( "d=i" => \$daysbefore );

my $filedate = getDate($daysbefore);
print "\n filedate is $filedate \n";
my @basedir = CONFIG::getBASEDIR();
print "\n array has basedir" . Dumper(@basedir);
$mon_  = "0" . $mon_  if ( defined $mon_  && $mon_ <= 9 );
$mday_ = "0" . $mday_ if ( defined $mday_ && $mday_ <= 9 );

foreach (@basedir) {
    my $both = $_;
    print "\n dir is $both \n";
    for ( keys %{$circle} ) {
        my $path     = $both;
        my $circleid = $_;
        print "\n circle is $circleid \n";
        my $circleidvalue = $circle->{$_};
        my $file_csv_path = "/opt/offline/reports/$circleid";
        my %sdp_hash      = ();
        print "\n file is $file_csv_path csv file \n";
        if ( -d "$file_csv_path" ) {
        } else {
            mkdir( "$file_csv_path", 0755 );
        }

        my $csv_new_file
            = $file_csv_path
            . "\/FDP_"
            . $circleid
            . "_SDPINCOMINGTPSREPORT_"
            . $mday_ . "_"
            . $mon_ . "_"
            . $year_ . "\.csv";
        print "\n file is $csv_new_file \n";
        print "\n date:$year_-$mon_-$mday_ \n";

        open( DATA, ">>", $csv_new_file );
        $path = $path . $circleid . "/Reporting/EN/Sdp";
        print "\n *****path is $path \n";
        my @filess = glob("$path/*");

        foreach my $file (@filess) {
            print "\n Filedate ---------> $filedate file is $file \n";
            if ( $file =~ /.*_sdp.log.$filedate-*/ ) {
                print "\n found file for $circleid \n";
                my $x;
                my $log       = $file;
                my @a         = split( "-", $file );
                my $starttime = $a[3];
                my $endtime   = $starttime;
                my $sdpid;
                my $sdpid_value;
                $starttime = "$filedate $starttime:00:00";
                $endtime   = "$filedate $endtime:59:59";
                open( FH, "<", "$log" ) or die "cannot open < $log: $!";

                while (<FH>) {
                    my $line = $_;
                    print "\n line is $line \n";
                    chomp($line);
                    $line =~ s/\s+$//;
                    my @a = split( ";", $line );
                    $sdpid = $a[4];
                    my $stat = $a[3];
                    $x->{$sdpid}->{$stat}++;
                }
                close(FH);
                print "\n Dumper is x:" . Dumper($x) . "\n";
                foreach my $sdpidvalue ( keys %{$x} ) {
                    print "\n sdpvalue us: $sdpidvalue \n";
                    if ( exists( $x->{$sdpidvalue}->{processed} ) ) {
                        $processed = $x->{$sdpidvalue}->{processed};
                    } else {
                        $processed = 0;
                    }
                    if ( exists( $x->{$sdpidvalue}->{discarded} ) ) {
                        $discarded = $x->{$sdpidvalue}->{discarded};
                    } else {
                        $discarded = 0;
                    }
                    my $sth_new1 = $dbh->prepare("select id from sdp_details where sdp_name='$sdpid' ");
                    print "\n sth new is " . Dumper($sth_new1);
                    $sth_new1->execute();
                    while ( my $row1 = $sth_new1->fetchrow_hashref ) {
                        $sdpid_value = $row1->{'id'};
                        print "\n in hash rowref from sdp_details table " . Dumper($sdpid_value);
                    }
                    my $sth_check
                        = $dbh->prepare(
                        "select processed,discarded from sdp_incoming_tps where circle_id='$circleidvalue' and sdp_id='$sdpid_value' and start_time='$starttime' and end_time='$endtime'"
                        );
                    print "\n Dumper for bhdatabase statement is " . Dumper($sth_check);
                    $sth_check->execute();
                    my $duplicate_row = 0;
                    my ( $success_, $failure_ );
                    while ( my $row_dup = $sth_check->fetchrow_hashref ) {
                        print "\n row_dup is " . Dumper($row_dup);
                        $duplicate_row = 1;
                        $success_ += $row_dup->{'processed'};
                        $failure_ += $row_dup->{'discarded'};
                    }
                    if ( $duplicate_row == 0 ) {
                        my $sth
                            = $dbh->prepare(
                            "insert into sdp_incoming_tps (id,circle_id,start_time,end_time,processed,discarded,sdp_id) select nextval('sdp_incoming_tps_id'),'$circleidvalue','$starttime','$endtime','$processed','$discarded','$sdpid_value' "
                            );
                        $sth->execute();
                    } else {
                        $success_ += $processed;
                        $failure_ += $discarded;
                        my $sth
                            = $dbh->prepare(
                            "update sdp_incoming_tps set processed=$success_,discarded=$failure_ where circle_id='$circleidvalue' and sdp_id='$sdpid_value' and start_time='$starttime' and end_time='$endtime'"
                            );
                        $sth->execute();
                    }
#                    my $file_csv_path = "/opt/offline/reports/$circleid";
#                    my %sdp_hash      = ();
#                    if ( -d "$file_csv_path" ) {
#                    } else {
#                        mkdir( "$file_csv_path", 0755 );
#                    }
#                    my $csv_new_file = $file_csv_path . "\/FDP_" . $circleid . "_SDPINCOMINGTPSREPORT_". $mday_ . "_" . $mon_ . "_" . $year_ . "\.csv";
                    print "\n file is $csv_new_file \n";
                    print "\n date:$year_-$mon_-$mday_ \n";
                    close(DATA);
                    open( DATA, ">>", $csv_new_file ) or die("cant open file : $! \n");
                    print "\n csv new file is $csv_new_file \n";
                    my $sth_new2 = $dbh->prepare("select * from sdp_details");
                    $sth_new2->execute();

                    while ( my $row1 = $sth_new2->fetchrow_hashref ) {
                        my $sdpid = $row1->{'id'};
                        $sdp_hash{$sdpid} = $row1->{'sdp_name'};
                    }
                    #print "\n resultant sdp hash".Dumper(%sdp_hash);
                    #$mon_="0".$mon_;
                    print "\n timestamp being matched is $year_-$mon_-$mday_ \n";
                    print "\n circle id value is $circleidvalue \n";
                    my $sth_new
                        = $dbh->prepare(
                        "select * from sdp_incoming_tps where date_trunc('day',start_time)='$year_-$mon_-$mday_' and circle_id='$circleidvalue'"
                        );
                    $sth_new->execute();
                    print "\n final db line is " . Dumper($sth_new);
                    my $str     = $sth_new->{NAME};
                    my @str_arr = @$str;
                    shift(@str_arr);
                    shift(@str_arr);
                    my @upper = map { ucfirst($_) } @str_arr;
                    $upper[4] = "Sdp-Name";
                    my $st = join( ",", @upper );
                    $st = $st . "\n";
                    $st =~ s/\_/\-/g;
                    #print $fh "sep=,"; print $fh "\n";

                    print DATA $st;
                    while ( my $row = $sth_new->fetchrow_hashref ) {

                        print "\n found matching row \n";
                        my $row_line
                            = $row->{'start_time'} . ","
                            . $row->{'end_time'} . ","
                            . $row->{'processed'} . ","
                            . $row->{'discarded'} . ","
                            . $sdp_hash{ $row->{'sdp_id'} } . "\n";
                        print "\n row line matched is " . $row_line . "\n";
                        print DATA $row_line;
                    }
                    close(DATA);
                }
            } else {
                next;
            }
        }
    }
}

$dbh->disconnect;
```

Please help, how can I avoid this error.

Thanks in adv.

Comment: what's _value_ assigned in `max_connection` in `postgresql.conf` ??

Comment: @Winged,Hi I don't know how to check that..Can you please help me with the method ? Thanks

Comment: do you use `pgAdmin` or something else ??

Comment: in `psql` `SHOW max_connections;`

Comment: I use :  psql -U postgres -h 192.168.18.23 -d scs

Comment: I used the abv command and got 
scs=# SHOW max_connections;
 max_connections
-----------------
 100
(1 row)

Comment: for test purpose increase `max_connection` to 500 and try

Comment: Ohk @ Winged.. How to change it ?

Comment: the main problem is the resource leaks. What I mean is `connection to the db not closes,result set or readers not closed` you need to check your code where your using resources to link with  your database close   connection after the use.

Answer (score 5):

The immediate problem, as indicated by the error message, is that running all of those scripts at once requires more database connections than the server will allow.  If they run fine individually, then running them individually will fix that.

The underlying problem is that your crontab is wrong.  `* 1 * * *` will run all the scripts *every minute* from 0100 to 0159 each day.  If they take more than one minute to complete, then a new set will start before the previous set completes, requiring an additional set of database connections, which will run through the pool of available connections rather quickly.

I assume that you only need to run your daily scripts once per day, not sixty times, so change that to `5 1 * * *` to run them only once, at 0105.

If there's still an issue, run each one on a different minute (which is probably a good idea anyhow):

```
5 1 * * * /var/fdp/reportingscript/an_outgoing_tps_report.pl
10 1 * * * /var/fdp/reportingscript/an_processed_rule_report.pl
15 1 * * * /var/fdp/reportingscript/sdp_incoming_traffic_tps_report.pl
20 1 * * * /var/fdp/reportingscript/en_outgoing_tps_report.pl
25 1 * * * /var/fdp/reportingscript/en_processed_rule_report.pl
30 1 * * * /var/fdp/reportingscript/rs_incoming_traffic_report.pl
35 1 * * * /var/fdp/reportingscript/an_summary_report.pl
40 1 * * * /var/fdp/reportingscript/en_summary_report.pl
45 1 * * * /var/fdp/reportingscript/user_report.pl
```

Comment: Or run them sequentially: `1 1 * * * cd /var/dfp/reportingscript && ls ./*.pl | sh`